# SELECT COUNT within date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a count of emails received during a date range using MSSQL Express 2005. I've managed that much, but now I want to split out the data into what was done with it.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, COUNT(EmailAddress) 
  FROM mails 
  WHERE ReceivedTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) 
  GROUP BY EmailAddress
    HAVING COUNT(EmailAddress) > 10
```

That gives me a list of addresses who mailed more than 10 times in the last week, but we have another column that tells us what happened with the mail. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, 
  COUNT(ActionTaken WHERE ActionTaken="Deleted") AS Deleted,
  COUNT(ActionTaken WHERE ActionTaken="Replied") AS Replied,
  COUNT(ActionTaken WHERE ActionTaken="Read") AS Read,
  COUNT(EmailAddress) AS Total
  FROM mails 
  WHERE ReceivedTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) 
  GROUP BY EmailAddress
    HAVING COUNT(EmailAddress) > 10
```

I'm looking for a result set along these lines:

```
 EmailAddress     | Deleted | Replied | Read | Total
 ---------------------------------------------------
 user1@domain.com | 4       | 5       | 3    | 12
 user2@domain.com | 2       | 6       | 3    | 11
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with using OVER(PARTITION BY) clauses, but I've hit a wall. I realise the ActionTaken field isn't ideal, but I didn't build it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes for string literals so it works irrespective of [`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) settings.

```
SELECT EmailAddress,
       Sum(CASE WHEN ActionTaken = 'Deleted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Deleted,
       Sum(CASE WHEN ActionTaken = 'Replied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Replied,
       Sum(CASE WHEN ActionTaken = 'Read' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS [Read],
       Count(EmailAddress) AS Total
FROM   mails
WHERE  ReceivedTime >= Dateadd(DAY, -7, Getdate())
GROUP  BY EmailAddress
HAVING Count(EmailAddress) > 10
```

Comment: You just saved me what would almost certainly have been an entire day trying to get my head around aggregate functions for the sake of something that looks so simple now I see it! Thank you, that works perfectly!

Comment: @timbstoke - Glad to help. You can also use `PIVOT` but I prefer the `CASE` method as easier to remember and more flexible. Also with `PIVOT` adding additional columns to the base table can break the query unless you take care to use a derived table or CTE with only the relevant columns as the source.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EmailAddress,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTaken = 'Deleted' THEN ActionTaken END) AS Deleted,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTaken = 'Replied' THEN ActionTaken END) AS Replied,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ActionTaken = 'Read' THEN ActionTaken END)    AS [Read],
       COUNT(EmailAddress) AS Total
FROM mails
WHERE ReceivedTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY EmailAddress
HAVING COUNT(EmailAddress) > 10
```